# Trying to reach more people for My App ASO Integration

Tags: flutter, google-play, app-store-optimization

Maybe some of you know me, some of you don't. I have been trying to make an application on Flutter for about 2 years. During this process, I got help from people here and helped people in many places where I had difficulties. Finally, I finished my application and published it. Now I don't think I have too many software problems.

But I don't know how to reach my application to more people. I tried various paid advertising campaigns, but they are not sustainable. Since I also encountered such a problem, I wanted to search for my problem here again. As a result of my research, I discovered that the biggest traffic comes from the applications application market, so standing out in the application market is the most important thing. But I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Everyone talked about ASO, but no one specified how it should be applied or what should be used. I would be very happy if you could help me. The name of my application is Shakery, it is a coktail and drink sharing platform, you can discover and share the drinks you like, and while discovering the drinks, you can search recipes based on ingredients you have with a very easy to use interface. It is currently available on the Google Play Store.

Download Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shakery.app